# Discord Oauth2: How do I get & list guilds?

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, discord, dashboard

Some bots have dashboards and they have a page that says "manage servers". How do I get the guilds my bot is in, and list them? Here are some code snippets on how I get the authorized username, avatar, discriminator, etc.

````
  window.onload = () => {
    const fragment = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    const [accessToken, tokenType] = [fragment.get('access_token'), fragment.get('token_type')];

    if (!accessToken) {
        window.location.href('/')
    }

    fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
    headers: {
        authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`,
    },
    })
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        const { username, discriminator, avatar, id} = response;
        //set the welcome username string
        document.getElementById('h1').innerText = ` ${username}#${discriminator}`;

        //set the avatar image by constructing a url to access discord's cdn
        document.getElementById("avatar").src = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${id}/${avatar}.jpg`;
    })
    .catch(console.error);


};
                  </script>```

Thank you! :)
````

Answer (score 0):

As per what i have seen in most of the bots having such features, The possible ways are listed as follows:

1. [EJS](https://ejs.co)

- The bots that are made in javascript, they just make a `express` server and then use ejs in the same directory as of their bot.
  Example: https://github.com/Tomato6966/Musicium
  To be more specific how they do this: https://github.com/Tomato6966/Musicium/blob/main/dashboard/index.js

2. APIs

- You can make a api which has a route to return the guilds in the same directory as of your bot in your preferred language.

3. Client-Side Discord API
   **THIS METHOD IS NOT SAFE AT ALL**

If you really dont mind leaking your bot's token, You can make a api request on the client-side to the discord api as follows:

```js
fetch("https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/guilds", {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bot <TOKEN_HERE>"
    }
})
```

Comment: for the last method, is there any **safe** way to do it? how would the user get access to the bot token
?

Comment: All network requests can be found in the "Network" tab of the browser. So anyone can open the tab and see the request along with all the headers

Comment: Putting bot token on client is such a bad idea, so I'd not even list it as an option. I know you mentioned it's not safe at all, but I bet you some newbies won't understand what it actually means. Putting it as an option is kinda encouraging them.

Comment: they follow the same at their own risk